# No route found for "GET /img/glyphicons-halflings.png"

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, get, glyphicons

I have a question about symfony2 and bootstrap. I dont understand why I can load icons  image from environment "prod" but not from environment "dev". In dev, i get this error.

The route is "GET /img/glyphicons-halflings.png".

Image web/img/glyphicons-halflings.png is a symbolic link to ../../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png

I get this error with

```
http://my.web.site/app_dev.php/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

And get image with

```
http://my.web.site/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
```

**UPDATE**

I include bootstrap in this way:

```
{% stylesheets '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

When I use in prod this works

```
<span class="icon-edit"></span>
```

And I have this assetic configuration:

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ MyAwesomeBundle ]
    filters:
        lessphp:
            file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

I've also tried to create my collection:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        senso:
            inputs:
                - '../img/glyphicons-halflings.png'
            outputs:
                - 'img/glyphicons-halflings.png'
            filters:
                - ?lessphp
```

:dump create web/assetic/senso.png and web/assetic/senso_glyphicons-halflings.png but, ... how can works with senso*.png image?

Comment: sadly you cant use the * syntax for images... and you should ommit the lessphp on your image completely:) the ? tells assetic to apply the filter only in production.

Comment: your input image in the collection should better be something like "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap" - see my answer, i have included my assetic config for you.

Comment: Now works but with asset('css/bootstrap.css') instead of asset('@css_bootstrap'). With @css_bootstrap asset write simply /css_bootstrap. But ... now it works!!!

Comment: With {% stylesheet ... I get this error: [2/2] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("There is no "css_boostrap" asset.") in "SensorarioTrashwareBundle:Default:layout.html.twig".

Comment: i'll double-check and update the answer again. the @syntax can be used refering to the collection name. did you maybe rename the collections under assetic.assets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
assetic:
    use_controller: false
    filters:
         lessphp:
             file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php"
    assets:   
        img_bootstrap_glyphicons_black:
            inputs:
                -  "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png"
            output: "img/glyphicons-halflings.png"

        img_bootstrap_glyphicons_white:
            inputs:
                -  "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png"
        output: "img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png"

        css_bootstrap:
            inputs:
                -  "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"
            output: "css/bootstrap.css"
            filters:
                - lessphp

        js_bootstrap:
            inputs:
                -  "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/*.js"
            output: "js/bootstrap.js"
```

<kbd>config_dev.yml</kbd>

```
assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

<kbd>template</kbd>

```
{% stylesheets '@css_bootstrap' %}
<link href="{{ asset_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts '@js_bootstrap' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

after running `assetic:dump --no-debug` everything works flawlessly.

### general info

the **cssrewrite** filter used i.e. for `background-image: url("..")` is incompatible with the `@Bundle`-syntax.

```
{% stylesheets 
   '@AcmeYourBundle/Resources/public/css/your.css' 
   filter="cssrewrite" 
%}
```

doesn't work.

Furthermore, sources like `url("../img/image.png")` will fail in dev environment without cssrewrite and `assetic.use_controller: true` - possible workaround: use urls like `url("/img/image.png")` but not working with pages in subfolders.

you should keep in mind that ...

```
<img src="img/image.png">
```

... will for `hostname/app_dev.php/` and all other routes except `hostname/`.

solution:

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/image.png') }}">
```

### other solutions & tips

- when including img,css or js into your page always use twig's `asset()`, `{% stylesheets %}` or `{% javascripts %}` function.
- use relative urls in stylesheets i.e. `url("../img/image.png")`
- try setting `assetic.use_controller: false` in your `config_dev.yml` and dump your assets ... as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)
- create [asset collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691226/1832745) in `config.yml`, then dump your assets - see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17083720/1832745).
- use the cssembedded filter to include your images in css using data-uris - reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony2)
- configure your webserver to directly serve files inside img/css/js folders instead of routing through symfony
- use a different hostname (i.e. `project.dev` ) for the dev environment using `app_dev.php` as directory-index resulting in url's without `/app_dev.php/`

you can find some good information about this topic in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony2).

my personal workflow:

- local wildcard dns server introducing automatically generated urls like `project.dev` , project.prod , ... ( no `/app_dev.php/` problems )
- creating [asset collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16691226/1832745) in config.yml ( cleaner templates, more control over assets )
- [guard](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/guard-is-your-best-friend/) / [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) taskrunners instead of `assetic:dump --watch` ( re-dump on change but test and optimize aswell )
- [source-maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/?redirect_from_locale=de) and chrome-devtools instead of assetic's `assetic:dump --debug` ( see the real source files for combined files,less,sass,coffeescript, ... )
- tincr ( to save directly from devtools ) and livereload ( see changes instantly )